# Ударение в слове «вечеря»

Tags: орфоэпия

С детства мне казалось, что нужно говорить "вечЕря", но сейчас все чаще слышу "вЕчеря" (Тайная вечеря). Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари единодушны во мнении: вЕчеря.

Это показалось мне интересным:

*Толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка разъясняет: «Вéчеря – это собрание ограниченного числа лиц, осуществляющееся вечером, обычно втайне от остального общества». Как вы понимаете, это не обычный семейный ужин-застолье; здесь имеется в виду, прежде всего, тайная вéчеря Иисуса Христа с Его учениками (см. Матф. 26; Марка 14; Луки 22 и др.). Тогда Христос сказал: «...Сие творите в Моё воспоминание» (Луки 22:19). Поэтому в наших церквах проходит торжественный обряд Вéчери Господней, во время которого верующие принимают святые символы Его Тела и Крови.*  [Международная христианская газета](http://www.titel.ru/cz-archive/archive/november08/tochka-zrenia.html)

Answer (score 0):

[**ВЕ́ЧЕРЯ**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/22062/%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%AF), -и, жен. (стар. высок.).
То же, что ужин (в 1 знач.).
• Тайная вечеря (высок.) по евангельской притче: последний ужин Иисуса Христа с учениками, на котором Иисус Христос установил таинство причащения и сказал, что один из учеников предаст его.

*В**е**черя*
1) ужин, угощенье; вечеряти – пиршествовать, ужинать;
2) Вечеря Тайная – совершена была накануне дня смерти Господа, где Христос вкусил в последний раз пасхального агнца, установил таинство причащения, умыл ноги ученикам своим, предсказал Иуде предательство, а Петру – отречение и беседовал с учениками своими;
3) Вечеря любви (агапа) – обед для бедных, устраиваемый богатыми подле храма, иначе трапеза.
(Полный православный богословский энциклопедический словарь. П. П. Сойкин. 1913)

*В**е**черя. Тайная в**е**черя* (неправильно веч**е**ря).
(Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке)

*В одной из притчей Евангельских будущее Царствие Небесное изображено, братие мои, под видом вечери брачной, которую один могущественный царь устроил по случаю бракосочетания сына своего.*
Херсонский Иннокентий, Архиепископ. Великий пост

Answer (score 0):

Нет такой русской словообразовательной модели, по которой от существительного 2-го скл.  муж. рода (вечер) образовывалось бы другое существительное (вечеря)путем добавления флексии -а. Образование слова "вечеря" напрямую от слова "вечер" как бы зависает в воздухе: ему нет аналогов (т.е. модели). Зато есть модель, по которой упомянутым способом существительные образуются от ГЛАГОЛОВ: засадИть - засАда, отравИть - отрАва, потерЯть - потЕря и т.д. В эту модель вписывается и вечерЯть - вечЕря. Словари дают орфоэпические варианты вечерЯть и вечЕрять, но не вЕчерять. Образование существительного "вечеря" от глагола по стандартной модели доказывает правильность произношения вечЕря и некорректность произношения вЕчеря. Владимир

Comment: *Нет такой русской словообразовательной модели* - спорно.  Лис - лиса, жираф - жирафа...

Comment: *Зато есть модель, по которой упомянутым способом существительные образуются от ГЛАГОЛОВ* = Вы будете удивлены, но в паре в**е**черя - вечерять первично как раз существительное, а вечерять - производное.